# meaning of "laborious comprises" in the context

Tags: meaning

Can you explain the meaning of `laborious  comprises` phrase in the text below. This paragraph is the 1st paragraph in http://www.all-art.org/art_20th_century/magritte1.html

My issue is actually the `comprises` word.

Longman and some other several dictionaries didn't help me

best regards

> The union of these two ethnic groups, with their so utterly 
>   incompatible mentalities, made it necessary to constantly reach
>   laborious  comprises, leading to legal and administrative
>   complications of such a nature that they tended more to deepen the
>   quarrel s than to settle them.

Comment: It's a typo. It should read _compromises_. That should make a lot more sense.

Comment: ok I got it now. Can you transform your comment to answer and let me accept it then. regards, thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo for "compromise".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Elendil's comment. If you replace "comprises" with "compromises" it makes a lot more sense.

The two ethnic groups had to make **compromises**:

> The settlement of differences by arbitration or by consent reached by mutual concessions.

which were difficult to reach and thus **laborious**:

> Toilsome; (...) mentally difficult.

(Definitions from Wiktionary)